# TensorFlow CNN behaving differently when batch is divided

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Initially I had the CNN working with the following code:

```
for i in range(1000):
    x_batch = []
    y_batch = []
    cost_ = 0.

    x_batch = x
    y_batch = y_data

    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x_batch, Y: y_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})
    cost_ += (sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_batch, Y: y_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5}))
    print(cost_)
```

But then I realized that I could not use larger datasets because it would quickly use all the memory available.
Instead I rewrote the code as follows:

```
for i in range(1000):
    x_batch = []
    y_batch = []
    cost_ = 0.
    for i in range(0, len(y_data), 100):
        x_batch = x[i:i+100]
        y_batch = y_data[i:i+100]

        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x_batch, Y: y_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})
        cost_ += (sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x_batch, Y: y_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5}))
    print(cost_)
```

It is supposed to partition the input into batches to reduce the amount of memory used for the video card. The problem is that now it is not getting the same accuracy as before.
The accuracy was 89% initially, and now it is only 33%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching from `Gradient Descent` to `Stochastic Gradient Descent` you need to keep some things in mind.

1. batch size can make an impact on the final performance of the neural net. I would try 128 or 256.

   > A typical minibatch size is 256, although the optimal size of the minibatch can vary for different applications and architectures.
2. you want to use a smaller learning rate, and maybe try incorporating learning rate decay.

   > learning rate α is typically much smaller than a corresponding learning rate in batch gradient descent because there is much more variance in the update.
3. You should randomize your training data on each epoch.

   > If the data is given in some meaningful order, this can bias the gradient and lead to poor convergence.

All the quotes are provided from [this article.](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/OptimizationStochasticGradientDescent/) It may be worth looking further into differences between gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent.